# Calculate the difference between two integers in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code, i was trying to calculate the difference between sales and expenditure..I have to query the database differently in order to achieve this. I am looking for a simple way to do this or a better way to achieve the same with the code below:

```
dref= dref.child("KatakaExpenditure");
dreff= dref.child("KatakaSales");

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int totalAmount = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                    totalAmount += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
                }


                textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmount));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        dreff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int totalAmountt = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                    totalAmountt += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
                }


                textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmountt));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });


        textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmountt));

int profit = totalAmountt - totalAmount;
Where totalAmount is the **dref= dref.child("KatakaExpenditure");
** and totalAmountt is **dreff= dref.child("KatakaSales");**
```

Comment: Did you get wrong value? Or got right value like you expected but searching for better way to do this? Because I think you won't get the right value with that code.

Comment: @koceeng i have heard no luck at all..the two variables, totalAmount and totalAmountt cannot be accessed outside their respective methods...i just thought it could be done that way, but it is not working