# getting the difference of two firebase results

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i have the following code that i intend to use to find the profit between sales and expenditure:

```
DatabaseReference dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference dreff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref = dref.child("KatakaExpenditure");
    dreff = dreff.child("KatakaSales");


    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            int totalAmount = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                totalAmount += dogExpenditure.getAmount();


            }






            textView4.setText("Your total Expenditure for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmount));
             amounta = totalAmount;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

    dreff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        int totalAmountt = 0;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                totalAmountt += dogExpenditure.getAmount();


            }


            textView5.setText("Your total Sales for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmountt));
            amountb = totalAmountt;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

amountc = amountb - amounta;

```
    textView3.setText("Your total Profit for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(amountc));

}
```

however the code gives me a 0 value for this **textView3.setText("Your total Profit for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(amountc));** line of code..any ideas on how to calculate this math **amountc = amountb - amounta;**??? thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are setting the `textView3.setText("Your total Profit for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(amountc));`

Comment: amountc = amountb - amounta;

        textView3.setText("Your total Profit for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(amountc));

Comment: i have two integers which are global: they are int amounta; and int amountb;

Comment: The values amounta and amountb are set on an event. There is a chance that the amountc is being set before the events are called. Try setting the `amountc = amountb - amounta; textView3.setText("Your total Profit for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(amountc));` inside `onDataChange`

Comment: This is the third time in a day you've asked the exact same question ([previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782087/run-two-queries-in-firebase), [oldest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764759/calculate-the-difference-between-two-integers-in-firebase)). Please post a question only once. If you have additional information, edit your original question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my questions are not being answered and i am so desparate..forgivee me man

Comment: I understand you have a real question, but reposting it is not the solution. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255371/1-user-reposting-same-question-over-and-over

Comment: @developeralways there are two events here... dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() and  dreff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() .. is there a way to make this two events into one event. because i am doing two data retrievals from two child(s)

Comment: Create a class implementing `ValueEventListener()` and implement the logic in a single place.

Comment: gotcha trying it noww